# PyQt4.QtGui import error

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

I have installed PyQt4 package for python3 and the PyQt4 library files are available at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4. When I import PyQt4 there is no problem but when I try to import QtGui from PyQt4 it shows me the following error log.

```
>>> import PyQt4
>>> from PyQt4 import QtGui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so: undefined symbol: PyString_Type
>>>
```

Comment: Installed it how, and on what platform?